# Threads synchronizing in Java, IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I am trying to synchronize two threads - the "Main" thread, and a runnable. I get the IllegalMonitorStateException, but I do not completelty understand what "you do not have the lock of the object" means.

Here is my code:

```
public class ThreadsTest {
    private static ThreadsTest instance;
    public volatile boolean flag = false;

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("first");

        this.flag = true;

    }

    public Runnable mDrawer = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            synchronized (ThreadsTest.getInstance()) {
                while (flag == false)
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        System.out.println("second");
                    }
            }



        }
    };

    public static ThreadsTest getInstance() {
        if (ThreadsTest.instance == null) {
            ThreadsTest.instance = new ThreadsTest();
        }
        return ThreadsTest.instance;
    }

    private ThreadsTest() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadsTest t = ThreadsTest.getInstance();
        t.mDrawer.run();
        t.doStuff();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may call `wait()` method only on objects you synchronizing on.
So, since you have `synchronized (ThreadsTest.getInstance())`, you must write `ThreadsTest.getInstance().wait()`.

Not sure what you trying to test here exactly, if it's just basic thread sync sample, then you should change your code to

```
public class ThreadsTest {
    private static ThreadsTest instance;
    public volatile boolean flag = false;

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("first");
        this.flag = true;
        synchronized (getInstance()) {
            getInstance().notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public Runnable mDrawer = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            synchronized (ThreadsTest.getInstance()) {
                while (flag == false)
                    try {
                        ThreadsTest.getInstance().wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        System.out.println("second");
                    }
            }



        }
    };

    public static ThreadsTest getInstance() {
        if (ThreadsTest.instance == null) {
            ThreadsTest.instance = new ThreadsTest();
        }
        return ThreadsTest.instance;
    }

    private ThreadsTest() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadsTest t = ThreadsTest.getInstance();
        new Thread(t.mDrawer).start();
        Thread.sleep(1000L); // let other thread start, so it won't skip our notify()
        t.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct note indeed. I did change the code, and I now call ThreadsTest.getInstance().wait(). Unfortunately, the result of this is that my application "freezes".

Comment: Erm :) Of course, since there's no other thread in your app to send your `wait()` signal to wake up. I'll update answer to reflect this

Comment: Thanks you, mate! Hallelujah !I now have a good idea what and why freezes