# IllegalMonitorStateException in code

Tags: java, multithreading, illegalmonitorstateexcep

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("1.. ");
        synchronized (args) {

            System.out.println("2..");

            try {
                Thread.currentThread().wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("3..");
        }

    }
}
```

I am getting `IllegalMonitorStateException` monitor exception in this code. As per my understanding, because of synchronized block around `args` which is string array object, current thread must have acquired the lock and with the wait method, I am release the lock.

Can someone explain me the reason behind this exception?

Comment: Um, there are no threads being created here except the primary one unless I'm missing something. Please post your full stacktrace.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: You are holding the monitor for the args object but calling `wait()` on the current thread object. You need to call `wait()` on an object that you are holding a monitor for. See e.g. this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773807/threads-synchronizing-in-java-illegalmonitorstateexception?rq=1

Comment: Questions about `IllegalMonitorStateException` while holding a lock for one object and calling `wait()` on another have been asked here a couple of times. Why is this question upvoted?

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `wait()` on `Thread.currentThread()`. Before calling `wait()` on any object, you must own the monitor *of this object*, by the way of a synchronized block synchronizing *on this object*. So what is missing is

```
synchronized(Thread.currentThread()) {
    Thread.currentThread().wait();
}
```

That said, calling `wait()` on a Thread object is not something you should do, and probably shows that you have not understood what `wait()` does, especially given that you don't have any other thread calling `notify()` or `notifyAll()`. Synchronizing on the arguments passed to the main method is also a very strange choice. `wait()` is a very low-level method that should rarely be used, even if you fully understand what it does. For a better answer, you should explain what you actually want this code to do.

Comment: thanks JB. this was my test programm to understand the functionality of wait. i got the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

From `IllegalMonitorStateException` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor **without owning the specified monitor**

From `Object#notify()` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29)

> A thread becomes the owner of the object's monitor in one of three ways:
>
> - By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
> - **By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes on the object**.
> - For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method of that class.

So since thread is executing block synchronized on `args` object

```
synchronized (args) {
    //...
}
```

you should call `args.wait()` instead `Thread.currentThread().wait();` .

Answer (score 0):

Hi ankit i assume you are trying to learn some basic concepts of multithreading. 
try to get hold of some good online tutorials :http://www.javaworld.com/jw-04-1996/jw-04-threads.html

or try some basic good book. [http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060)

The program you wrote actually doesn't need synchronization as there is only one thread (main). I know you are just trying your hands, therefore giving some  insights. Even if you correctly called wait method on args(args.wait()) or  synchronized on Thread.currentThread your thread may goes into indefinite wait (making your program unresponsive) because there is no other thread to notify your main thread.

Comment: yaah i knew that there are no threads other than main thread in programm, was just trying to get hold on normal threading concept. bdw thanks for helping me out